# how to know when shared preference is done writing

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two activities. Activity A has a button which starts activity B. When you hit the back button in activity B it restarts activity A. Also when the back button is hit it goes to the onStop method for activity B and in this point I update shared preferences for the user. Basically I'm storing player data on the shared preferences but the problem is when activity A is restarted I also load the same shared preferences but it doesn't show the updated data that I saved while activity B was stopped. I reload the app and it shows the up to date data. So it seems that while it is being saved while activity B is being stopped there isn't enough time for when it is loaded while activity A is being restarted. So how can I tell whether the shared preferences have finished being written to or not? Basically I want to load the shared preferences once I know for sure the shared preferences has been updated, is that possible?

I am using commit method:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() 
{
    Long dist = (long)treadmill_.Mod.distance_;
    Long newdist = dist + PlayerInfoManager.getInstance().getDistanceTraveled();
    PlayerInfoManager.getInstance().setDistanceTraveled(newdist);

    float fastestSaved = PlayerInfoManager.getInstance().getFastestSpeedAcheived();
    float fastestInSess = treadmill_.Mod.fastestSpeed;
    if(fastestSaved<fastestInSess)
        PlayerInfoManager.getInstance().setFastestSpeedAcheived(fastestInSess);

    Long time = (long)treadmill_.Mod.time_;
    Long newTime = time + PlayerInfoManager.getInstance().getTotalTimeRan();
    PlayerInfoManager.getInstance().setTotalTimeRan(newTime);

    Log.e("OnStop", "at Run, run, run");
    super.onStop();
}
```

In PlayerInfoManager.getinstance().setDistanceTraveled(newdist):

```
public void setDistanceTraveled(Long distanceTraveled) 
{
    DistanceTraveled = distanceTraveled;
    Editor edit = SP.edit();
    edit.putLong("DistanceTraveled", distanceTraveled);
    edit.commit(); 
}
```

SP is the sharedPreference instance:

```
private SharedPreferences SP;
```

For activity A when it restarts:

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    LoadStats();
    Log.e("onrestart", " ");
}

public void LoadStats()
{
    PIM.loadAll();
    Dis.setText(Long.toString(PIM.getDistanceTraveled()));
    FastestSpeed.setText(Float.toString(PIM.getFastestSpeedAcheived()));
    TotalTime.setText(Long.toString(PIM.getTotalTimeRan()));
    KeepItUp.setText(Long.toString(PIM.getLongestTimeInKeepItUp()));
}

    public void loadAll()
{// load all saved player data from sharedpreferences
    DistanceTraveled = SP.getLong("DistanceTraveled", 0L);
    FastestSpeedAcheived = SP.getFloat("FastestSpeed", 0.0f);
    TotalTimeRan = SP.getLong("TotalTime", 0L);
    LongestTimeInKeepItUp = SP.getLong("KeepItUp", 0L);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `onRestart()` can you try with `onResume()`?

Comment: It doesn't go to onResume(). I don't have control which method it goes to. I do have loadAll in onResume() as well since it should load the player data once the activity A starts.

Answer (score 0):

using `.commit()` method will make sure your data has been saved.
see the android doc for sharedPreferences.

[see the commit and apply method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) instead since this occurs before `onStop`

From the documentation

> Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity. This is typically used to commit unsaved changes to persistent data, stop animations and other things that may be consuming CPU, etc. Implementations of this method must be very quick because the next activity will not be resumed until this method returns.

You might want to see the description of an [Activity's lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).